# пропадает Scroll при смещении TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Друзья а кто сталкивался - пытаюсь реализовать смещение TableView вверх при появлении клавиатуры. После смещения пропадает scroll и прокрутить TableView нельзя.  В чем проблема?

```
-(void) keybordWillShow: (NSNotification *) notification {
NSDictionary *keyboardPosition = notification.userInfo;
NSValue *keyboardFrameTMP = [keyboardPosition objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
CGRect keyboardFrame = [keyboardFrameTMP CGRectValue];
NSInteger tableViewOffset =keyboardFrame.size.height;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{
  _myTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-tableViewOffset, 0, 0, 0);
}];}
```

`scrollEnabled = YES` не помогает

Comment: странный у вас код, вы странный inset ставите, UIEdgeInsetsMake(-tableViewOffset, 0, 0, 0). Посмотрите вот эту библиотеку: https://github.com/kirpichenko/EKKeyboardAvoiding. Там не очень сложный код обработки.

Comment: Согласен с @AndrewRomanov, проблема явно в `_myTableView.contentInset`

Comment: нормальный там инсет, зря вы человека конфузите - все как эпл рекомендует https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7

Comment: спс, а то я уже под-растроился

Comment: для dynamic вариант с scrollIndicatorInsets помогает - все отображается. static - таки не получилось. разбираемся...

Answer (score 1):

_myTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-tableViewOffset, 0, 0, 0);

В этой строчке вы сдвигаете контент вью таблицы вверх на tableViewOffset величину, что по коду равна высоте клавиатуры. Соответсвенно, область, которая реагирует на скролл - сместилась.

Я бы вам предложил не работать в таком ключе. Используйте NSLayoutConstraint и изменяйте величину определенного констреинта при появлении клавиатуры.